# program to check for substring. What's wrong

Tags: c, string, substring, runtime-error

A program to check if 2nd string is a substring of first string. It displays "Yes" for all cases, Moreover, I get a runtime error whenever i give the second string as 'q**q', why is it so..? * stand for any letter.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char str1[20], str2[20];
    int l1, l2, i1, i2=0;
    gets(str1);
    gets(str2);
    l1=strlen(str1);
    l2=strlen(str2);
    if(l1>=l2)
    {
        for(i1=0; i1<=l1-l2+i2, i2<l2; i1++)
        {
            if(str2[i2]==str1[i1])
            i2++;
        }
        if(i2==l2)
            printf("Yes");
        else
            printf("No");
    }
    else
        printf("No");

    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is your code really indented this way?  Fix that first, it will be more readable.

Comment: You could use the function `char *strstr( const char *s1,  const char *s2)` define in `string.h`[link](http://www.edcc.edu/faculty/paul.bladek/c_string_functions.htm). Or you are trying to achieve this in order to learn and practice C?

Comment: To find error like this you should use a debugger, and see where the error occurs, besides, try not to use variables with l and 1, it looks the same and it quite confusing. I recommend you to read "code complete",this is a excellent book which will give you best practices for code readability

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition in the for statement

```
for(i1=0; i1<=l1-l2+i2, i2<l2; i1++)
```

really doesn't make sense. The code `i1<=l1-l2+i2, i2<l2` evaluates the part before the comma, **discards the result**, and then evaluates the part after the comma.

Perhaps you intend to write `i1<=l1-l2+i2 && i2<l2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 int substring(char *s,char *t)
         {
                int i, j, k;

                for (i = 0; s[i]; i++)
                {   for (j = i, k = 0; t[k] && s[j] == t[k]; j++, k++)
                        ;
                    if (k > 0 && !t[k])
                        {
                             return i;
                        }

                       return -1;
               }
        }
```

This is working code...
As your solution fails for 
Input string -- anshulanananans, Search string -- anans